# Ionic, Apple AppStore Submission

Tags: ios, app-store, ionic-framework

When I upload my app to app store, I encounter this problem while validation:

Error Message:

Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for sfnt2woff

And in the error log, I get this:

Unable to validate your application:
The path '/var/folders/hm/.../MyApp.ipa' does not contain a file

I use Ionic Framework for my app. It is a very simple app.

I am using XCode 7.1 and recently tested my app on iOS 9. Everything works fine (Build Success, Achive Success) up until the submission step.

Can anyone tell what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

If this is a Cordova project, check inside your www folder. You probably have an ionicons folder in there with a binary named "sfnt2woff" deep inside it. Just delete that binary (or the entire build folder) and archive again.

Comment: OMG I spent 2 days trying to fix the problem. Thanks so much.